# Memory error when fitting convnet using Tensorflow/Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, memory, deep-learning

I'm attempting to fit a convnet to a fairly large dataset of bird images. The training set consists of 58388 224x224 images with 3 colour channels, giving a training tensor of size (58388, 224, 224, 3).

This takes up 32.74gb of RAM. I'm running an Nvidia Geforce RTX 3090 with 24gb of RAM.

See my code below for constructing, compiling and fitting my model.

```
num_classes = len(np.unique(y_train))
img_height = X_train.shape[1]
img_width = X_train.shape[2]

model = Sequential([
  layers.Rescaling(1./255, input_shape=(img_height, img_width, 3)),
  layers.Conv2D(16, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(32, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same', activation='relu'),
  layers.MaxPooling2D(),
  layers.Flatten(),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(num_classes)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

history = model.fit(
    X_train, 
    y_train,
    batch_size=32,
    epochs=25,
    validation_split=0.03,
)
```

When I run the code I get the following error:

```
InternalError: Failed copying input tensor from /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0 to /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 in order to run _EagerConst: Dst tensor is not initialized.
```

Implying I don't have enough memory to train the model on GPU. Everything I see online when I google the problem says to reduce the batch size. I've tried reducing the batch size all the way to 1 and I still have the same problem. It's my understanding that only a single batch at once is transferred to GPU RAM when training, not the entire dataset. I don't understand the problem I'm having.

I've been successful in training a model using the tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory function to create a dataset generator.

My question is: is there a way to train the model without using generators i.e. just holding the dataset in memory?

Comment: Since you're passing `x` and `y` values, it can be assumed these are arrays. Arrays are completely loaded into memory. You can't partially load arrays like how datasets use batches. If you want to do that, convert them to a dataset using `ImageDataGenerator.flow()` then set the batch size as needed. Otherwise, as you said "This takes up 32.74gb of RAM" and you're running a 3090 "with 24gb of RAM". You can't fit 32.74GB into 24GB of memory.

Comment: @Djinn Excellent, thanks. I was under the impression that not all the data was read from process to GPU memory when you passed arrays to fit. This makes sense and is what I expected, it just seemed weird to me that you could create a generator that read from disk but not one that read from memory, but  `ImageDataGenerator.flow()` does this, I just wasn't aware of it.